# Making function call stop after given time budget

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have three functions f1(x), f2(x) and f3(x) returning a result (imagine API calls, no control over the functions). Those functions can take an undetermined amount of time to end when called (but usually under 1s). Now I need to call all those functions and select the best result but under the constrain that I need to return some result in max t miliseconds. Pseudocode:

```
def select_result(x, max_t):
    r1 = f1(x) # but stop if it takes longer than max_t miliseconds
    r2 = f2(x) # but stop if it takes longer than max_t miliseconds
    r3 = f3(x) # but stop if it takes longer than max_t miliseconds
    return max(r1, r2, r3) # or None if it took too long
```

How can I achieve that in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subprocess for each function call. The `subprocess.run()` method accepts a timeout parameter that is the number of seconds the until the child is killed. From the docs:

> The timeout argument is passed to Popen.communicate(). If the timeout expires, the child process will be killed and waited for. The TimeoutExpired exception will be re-raised after the child process has terminated.

So its necessary to handle `TimeoutExpired` exceptions that will be thrown if any of the processes do end up exceeding the timeout limit.

Another option is to use signals to set timers and send a `SIGLARM`. This has the advantage of being a little less destructive, since you can modify the called functions to properly handle the signal when it comes, giving them a chance to shutdown cleanly. The downside is that signals can be tricky to program, whereas the subprocess option is a pretty self-contained solution right out of the box.